# Zookeeper vs In-memory-data-grid vs Redis

Tags: redis, apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing, hazelcast

I've found different zookeeper definitions across multiple resources. Maybe some of them are taken out of context, but look at them pls:

1. > [A canonical example of Zookeeper usage is distributed-memory computation...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662995/explaining-apache-zookeeper)
2. > [ZooKeeper is an open source Apache™ project that provides a centralized infrastructure and services that enable synchronization across a cluster.](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/hadoop/zookeeper/)
3. > [Apache ZooKeeper is an open source file application program interface (API) that allows distributed processes in large systems to synchronize with each other so that all clients making requests receive consistent data.](http://searchcloudcomputing.techtarget.com/definition/Apache-ZooKeeper)

I've worked with Redis and Hazelcast, that would be easier for me to understand Zookeeper by comparing it with them.

*Could you please compare Zookeeper with in-memory-data-grids and Redis?*

1. If distributed-memory computation, how does zookeeper differ from in-memory-data-grids?
2. If synchronization across cluster, than how does it differs from all other in-memory storages? The same in-memory-data-grids also provide cluster-wide locks. Redis also has some kind of transactions.
3. If it's only about in-memory consistent data, than there are other alternatives. Imdg allow you to achieve the same, don't they?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperOver.html

By default, Zookeeper replicates all your data to every node and lets clients watch the data for changes. Changes are sent very quickly (within a bounded amount of time) to clients. You can also create "ephemeral nodes", which are deleted within a specified time if a client disconnects. ZooKeeper is highly optimized for *reads*, while writes are very slow (since they generally are sent to every client as soon as the write takes place). Finally, the maximum size of a "file" (znode) in Zookeeper is 1MB, but typically they'll be single strings.

Taken together, this means that zookeeper is not meant to store for much data, and definitely not a cache. Instead, it's for managing heartbeats/knowing what servers are online, storing/updating configuration, and possibly message passing (though if you have large #s of messages or high throughput demands, something like RabbitMQ will be much better for this task).

Basically, ZooKeeper (and Curator, which is built on it) helps in handling the mechanics of clustering -- heartbeats, distributing updates/configuration, distributed locks, etc.

It's not really comparable to Redis, but for the specific questions...

1. It doesn't support any computation and for most data sets, won't be able to store the data with any performance.
2. It's replicated to all nodes in the cluster (there's nothing like Redis clustering where the data can be distributed). All messages are processed atomically in full and are sequenced, so there's no real transactions. It can be USED to implement cluster-wide locks for your services (it's very good at that in fact), and tehre are a lot of locking primitives on the znodes themselves to control which nodes access them.
3. Sure, but ZooKeeper fills a niche. It's a tool for making a distributed applications play nice with multiple instances, not for storing/sharing large amounts of data. Compared to using an IMDG for this purpose, Zookeeper will be faster, manages heartbeats and synchronization in a predictable way (with a lot of APIs for making this part easy), and has a "push" paradigm instead of "pull" so nodes are notified very quickly of changes.

The quotation from the linked question...

> A canonical example of Zookeeper usage is distributed-memory computation

... is, IMO, a bit misleading. You would use it to orchestrate the computation, not provide the data. For example, let's say you had to process rows 1-100 of a table. You might put 10 ZK nodes up, with names like "1-10", "11-20", "21-30", etc. Client applications would be notified of this change automatically by ZK, and the first one would grab "1-10" and set an ephemeral node `clients/192.168.77.66/processing/rows_1_10`

The next application would see this and go for the next group to process. The actual data to compute would be stored elsewhere (ie Redis, SQL database, etc). If the node failed partway through the computation, another node could see this (after 30-60 seconds) and pick up the job again.

I'd say the canonical example of ZooKeeper is leader election, though. Let's say you have 3 nodes -- one is master and the other 2 are slaves. If the master goes down, a slave node must become the new leader. This type of thing is perfect for ZK.

Comment: This is one of the best Zookeeper definitions on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Consistency Guarantees
ZooKeeper is a high performance, scalable service. Both reads and write operations are designed to be fast, though reads are faster than writes. The reason for this is that in the case of reads, ZooKeeper can serve older data, which in turn is due to ZooKeeper's consistency guarantees:

Sequential Consistency
Updates from a client will be applied in the order that they were sent.

Atomicity
Updates either succeed or fail -- there are no partial results.

Single System Image
A client will see the same view of the service regardless of the server that it connects to.

Reliability
Once an update has been applied, it will persist from that time forward until a client overwrites the update. This guarantee has two corollaries:

If a client gets a successful return code, the update will have been applied. On some failures (communication errors, timeouts, etc) the client will not know if the update has applied or not. We take steps to minimize the failures, but the only guarantee is only present with successful return codes. (This is called the monotonicity condition in Paxos.)

Any updates that are seen by the client, through a read request or successful update, will never be rolled back when recovering from server failures.

Timeliness
The clients view of the system is guaranteed to be up-to-date within a certain time bound. (On the order of tens of seconds.) Either system changes will be seen by a client within this bound, or the client will detect a service outage.